# UILabel string release?

Tags: iphone, string, release, uilabel

I have an IBAction like this:

```
-(IBAction)
{
[kolikoZvanja setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i + ", [Data variables].zvanja]];
}
```

where `[Data variables].zvanja` changes through program, so `UILabel` changes too through program, do I need to `release` `kolikoZvanja` each time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to release those things which you retain. You retain things by calling a method including `new`, `alloc`, `copy` or `retain`.

You aren't calling `retain` anywhere in this method, so there is no reason you should call `release`.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not. If you release the label each time, you won't be able to set its text anymore, or you re alloc/init it each time and re-add it to the view.
The string displayed by the label is copied by it, so it is responsible for releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

`kolikoZvanja` is a property that is a pointer to a `UILabel`. Because you are setting only the `text` property of this `UILabel` you cannot release the `kolikoZvanja` which is your "access gate" for your `UILabel`. Releasing the `kolikoZvanja` would effect in loosing a pointer to your `UILabel` hence you would not be able to set it's `text` property.